# Calculating position/dimensions causes CSS transition to occur

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

So, here's an odd little edge case:

If you attach an element to the DOM with jQuery and then immediately call `addClass` on it, you won't get a CSS transition. However, if you call `position()`, `offset()`, `width()`, `css('left')`, or any other calculating method on any element between the attachment and the `addClass` call, you *will* get a CSS transition.

Here's a demonstration (requires WebKit): http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/pGZFN/

I'd like to fully understand why this is happening (bonus points for linking to the jQuery source code), and to find out if there's a workaround. I have a site where I want the `addClass` call to be conditional on an element's position, but I don't want the usual CSS transition to apply to the newly-created element.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `addClass()` inside a `setTimeout()` with a one-millisecond delay, it also triggers the transition:

```
var $box1 = $('<div class="box">').appendTo($('body'));;
var $box2 = $('<div class="box">').appendTo($('body'));;
setTimeout(function() {
    $box1.addClass('green');
    $box1.width();
    $box2.addClass('green');
}, 1);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pGZFN/4/

However, if you add the `green` class to either box before it's appended to the DOM, no transition occurs:

```
var $box2 = $('<div class="box green">').appendTo($('body'));;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pGZFN/5/

This leads me to suspect that it's not any particular calculating method that's triggering the transition, but rather the micro-delay caused by that method. Possibly you're encountering a race condition where the class is being added before the div is completely appended to the DOM.

In any event, I'd say the safest way to prevent your transition is to do exactly that -- add the class to the element before it's added to the DOM, instead of using `addClass()` to do so afterward.

Comment: It's not a race condition caused by a "micro-delay"; put `var startDate = new Date(); while (new Date() - startDate < 1000) {}` (a synchronous 1-second delay) in place of the `width()` call, and you get no CSS transition. The problem is that calculating a position forces the DOM to update. But I **need** to calculate that position after the element has been added to the DOM in order to determine whether I want to call `addClass`.

Comment: I can trigger the transition with a `setTimeout` and no calculations: http://jsfiddle.net/pGZFN/6/ -- If you need to calculate position after the element is added, then just create one CSS class without the transition, and a second with it.

Comment: Right, you'll always get a CSS transition when you use a timeout because the DOM updates from the event queue. Creating a separate CSS class without the transition proved to be unworkable in my case, because I want a reverse transition when the class is removed later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that works in my particular situation: Clone the element, add the class to the clone, and replace the original with the clone.

A demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/dbn5p/

It's not ideal, because you might have stored references to the original element that you don't want to break. And cloning may introduce other issues in some cases. So I'll happily accept anyone else's solution that solves the problem directly on the element.